# Finding wavelength of the centre of Stokes Ro-vibrational spectrum

Tags: spectroscopy, raman, ir-spectroscopy

I have the following rovibrational Raman spectrum for $N_2$:

[image]

and I am trying to calculate the "wavelength where the centre of the Stokes ro-vibrational spectrum would be observed" if the $N_2$ is excited with a 532nm Nd:YAG laser. I am very unsure of how to do this. I think I need to use the fact that Stokes transitions are given by $\tilde v = \tilde v_0 - 4BJ-6B$ ($B=$ rotational constant, $J=$ rotational quantum number and $\tilde v_0=$ excitation wavenumber) and that the separation between Stokes and Anti-Stokes lines is approx. $4B$. I don't really know how to make use of this information though nor what exactly is meant by the "centre" of the Stokes ro-vibrational spectrum. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me work through this.

Comment: You should draw out the rotational energy levels and transitions for this vibrational level, then you will understand how these transitions arise. Usually these are also shown in a textbook, if not for Raman then for IR and you could use these as a starting point. The principle is the same but the transition energy gaps are different in Raman vs  IR. You have all the info you need in the spectrum.